# Can I specify the degree of parallelism with SQL statement?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am enjoying working with Spark sql but faced an issue just before.
Spark sql spits the following error messages due to the limitation in RDD's size per partition; (INT_MAX).

```
16/03/03 15:41:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 142.2 in stage 4.0 (TID 929) on executor 10.1.100.116: java.lang.RuntimeException (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:828)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:127)
```

So I want to increase the number of partitions of each RDD to walk around this issue. Can I adjust them in Spark sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to increase the number of partitions?
Normally (and often) Spark choses a suitable number of partitions based on your cluster (or local machine) features.

If you look at [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections): "Normally, Spark tries to set the number of partitions automatically based on your cluster. However, you can also set it manually..."

From my personal experience, increasing the number of doesn't always lead to increase the efficiency of the processing, except if your are dataset is small (it fits in the memory of the machine) and if the machine has available idle cores to process the new partitions.

Regarding your question, there is a configuration property called `spark.default.parallelism` that you can set to control the level of parallelism, you can find it [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), and [here](http://www.bigsynapse.com/controlling-the-number-of-partitions-in-spark) you can find an explanation about the default Spark behaviour regarding deciding the number of partitions.

Manually setting the number of partition can be tricky and it is not flexible (you have to make sure to adjust this number when you execute the application on a different machine or cluster).